# MongoDB sort winingplan overrides hint

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I create a collection with three fields as described below. After that, I create an index over second field and executed a search using sort and hint operations.

Why - even using a hint over index created previously - MongoDB set sort as winningPlan?

I believe that if we filter data with some criteria and sort the result could be better, right?

**Collection**

```
> db.values.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5763ffebe5a81f569b1005e5"), "field1" : "A", "field2" : "B", "field3" : "C" }
```

**Indexes**

```
> db.values.getIndexes()
  [
    {
      "v" : 1,
      "key" : {
          "_id" : 1
      },
      "name" : "_id_",
      "ns" : "peftest.values"
    },
    {
      "v" : 1,
      "key" : {
          "field2" : 1
      },
      "name" : "field2_1",
      "ns" : "peftest.values"
    }
  ]
```

**Query and Explain**

```
> db.values.find({field2:"B"}).sort({field1:1}).hint({field2:1}).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "peftest.values",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "field2" : {
                "$eq" : "B"
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "field1" : 1
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "field2" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "field2_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "field2" : [
                                "[\"B\", \"B\"]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "apstrd14501d.intraservice.corp",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.2.4",
        "gitVersion" : "e2ee9ffcf9f5a94fad76802e28cc978718bb7a30"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: The inputStage says it fetched the data using the correct index *{"stage" : "IXSCAN", "keyPattern" : { "field2" : 1}, ...}*.

Answer (score 2):

I think the plan is what you expect but you look at it from the wrong perspective :)
The input stage of the sort is an index scan so the query plan uses the index at first and the pass the result data to the sort.